# This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, phonegap-build

I am new to the android studio

I have importing PhoneGap project into the android studio.

Here I am getting this error

```
This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
```

and I don't know how to use android studio

I did following steps.

1. node.js and PhoneGap and android studio installation
2. PhoneGap project creation
3. add the Android platform to PhoneGap project and build android
4. import the project into the studio (I have imported whole app not only android platform)

after this, I'm getting

```
Migrate Project to Gradle?
            This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
            More Information about migrating to Gradle
            Don't show this message again.
```

How can I solve this? and how to run the project? and how to proceed further in android studio+Phonegap project

Comment: Click on "More Information about migrating to Gradle". I think it will say something to the effect of using Eclipse to export to gradle first, before being able to import the Eclipse project to Android Studio. At least, that's what it used to say when Android Studio was still in Preview, the message may have changed since then.

Comment: Is it applicable for phonegap project? Why im asking this is, If i add platforms/android directory, I can able to run the project without doing anyhting. It have been running

Comment: A phone gap project is an android project. There is nothing magical going on with phone gap projects. A phone gap project is just an android project with a webview running inside of it.

Comment: How to add gradle to the project

Comment: Use Eclipse with the original project and export it to gradle from there. I forget what were the exact steps.  You'll have to use google for that.

Answer (score 0):

@Deen,
<s>according to this blog post - [Android Builds Now Using Gradle By Default](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/28/android-using-gradle) (2015-09-28), Gradle is the default.</s> See ***UPDATE***

However, in the last hour (it's 10:45 pm on 2015-12-04 in El Paso, Texas) I found out this may not be the case.

I have made an inquiry to the Nitobi Forum, PhoneGap Build's "official forum".
See: [Is Gradle the default build?](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/is-gradle-the-default-build)

In the meantime you should be able to force gradle with:

`<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />`

The documentation confirms as much. See: `Configuring`->`Preferences`->[`Android Only`](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#_android_only)

**NOTE:** *PhoneGap Build* is a cloud service to build Apps. It does not run in an IDE. *PhoneGap Build* is self-contained. See the Stack-overflow tag for more.

***UPDATE: 2015-12-05T22:19:32*** The response from other Volunteers on Nitobi indicate that PhoneGap removes the "default Gradle" within 24 hours of the announcement.

Best of Luck

Comment: @Deen, does this solve your issue? am using cordova 6.4.0 and android studio 2.23 so any help?